# Load the computed LDA models and print the most common words per topic

Tags: python, gensim, topic-modeling

I'm new to python. What I'm trying to do is to read 2 parameters via console.

1. parameter:path to a trained LDA model with gensim.
2. parameter:the number of most common words per topic which I want to get in return.

Now I want to print for all the topics the number of the most common words per topic. Now my question is how to get all the topics.

This is what I have so far:

```
import sys, getopt
import gensim

def main(argv):
   input_file = argv[0] #LDA Path
   number_of_words = argv[1] #Number of most common word per topic

   ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel.load(input_file, mmap=None) #load model
   ldamodel.print_topic(?, number_of_words)



if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

[Gensim doc](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html)

Thanks

Comment: ldamodel.print_topic(10, topn=5) <= with this code you print for 10 topics in your model the top 5 common words. Right? But why to look only at 10 topics..

Answer (score 0):

`get_topic_terms` does what you want. I think the number of topics is stored in `num_topics` variable, accessible through `ldamodel.num_topics`.

Comment: get_term_topics(word_id, minimum_probability=None)

 Returns most likely topics for a particular word in vocab.

Comment: You should look at `get_topic_terms`, not `get_term_topics`

Comment: Could you correct the two lines then?      ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel.load(input_file, mmap=None) #load model
   ldamodel.print_topic(?, number_of_words)